# Union and bit masking, how does this work?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, unions

here is some C code:

```
float phaseFrac(unsigned int inPhase)
{
    union { unsigned int itemp; float ftemp; } u;
    u.itemp = 0x3F800000 | (0x007FFF80 & ((inPhase)<<7));
    return u.ftemp - 1.f;
}
```

I can't wrap my head around the use of "union" here. Am I right in thinking that since both uint and float are 32 bits, the resulting bit pattern in union is reinterpreted as a float value? Or is there some other magic here?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  A union is like a struct except that all the data members have overlappimg storage, so if you write a field of one type and then read back a field of some other type it will reinterpret the bits of the first type as a value of the second type.

The code looks weird here because the union is being defined inside a function.  Typically one would declare a union at file scope like one would declare a struct, but here since the goal is bit mangling rather than data storage it's being done locally.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it invokes undefined behavior: accessing a different member of the union than the one last modified.  However, most C compilers will do as you suppose, and interpret the bit pattern as a float, and these days most everybody uses IEEE format floats.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're correct.  float and int are 32 bits.  My guess is that if you attempt to assign 0x3F800000 to a float, it's like assigning 1065353216 which has a completely different bit configuration saved as a float, which would explain why the int is needed.

The float is needed to obtain a particular effect subtracting 1 that you wouldn't get subtracting 1 from int for the same reason.

Comment: AFAICR, `int` isn't guaranteed to be 32 bits - or guaranteed to be of any other particular bit length, either. Though `float` probably would have a fixed bit length. Ah, the wonders of C.

Comment: True, and in my opinion that method was coded badly for that reason.  Should have been an array of 4 bytes instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should prove to be helpful with an example similar to your question :

http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/publications/CCSCWeb.doc